# need to fetch a data from two different sheets using there ids and headers/

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sheet1]

With this sheet1 have a list of values,

I need fetch the status "In-Progress" & "Completed" based on the ID and lesson list

[image: Sheet2]

Status from sheet1 must be pasted matching ID and Topic in sheet2 with help of VBA, Can someone guide on this topic to achieve the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an example of possible solution (or maybe will give you way forward):

```
Sub test()
    Dim dic As Object: Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = Sheet1
    Dim dest As Worksheet: Set dest = Sheet2
    Dim id As Range, Topic As Range, Status As Range
    Dim searchStr1$, searchStr2$

    With src
        Set id = .Rows(1).Find("ID") 'assume that header in row 1
        Set Topic = .Rows(1).Find("Topic") 'assume that header in row 1
        Set Status = .Rows(1).Find("Status") 'assume that header in row 1
        Set rng = .Range(id.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, id.Column).End(xlUp))

        For Each cl In rng
            dic.Add cl.Value2 & .Cells(cl.Row, Topic.Column).Value2, _
            .Cells(cl.Row, Status.Column).Value2
        Next cl
    End With
    With dest
        Set rng = .Range(.[A2], .Cells(.Rows.Count, id.Column).End(xlUp))
        For Each cl In rng
            searchStr1 = cl.Value2 & .[B1].Value2
            searchStr2 = cl.Value2 & .[C1].Value2
            If dic.exists(searchStr1) Then cl.Offset(, 1).Value2 = dic(searchStr1)
            If dic.exists(searchStr2) Then cl.Offset(, 2).Value2 = dic(searchStr2)
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

**test**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in Sheet2 after modifying for the correct worksheets and ranges, then fill right and down.

[image: =INDEX($C:$C, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(($A$1:$A$5=$E2)*($B$1:$B$5=F$1)), 1))]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried the same way you did in same sheet, I got result "Zero" 0, hopefully a VBA coding might help me better

Comment: Well, I would suggest you get started on that.